# Validar usuário digitou apenas número - C

Tags: c, validação

Tenho uma string declarada da seguinte forma:

```
char    cpf[12];
```

Quero validar que o usuário digitou apenas números quando ele teclar ENTER.

Capturei o valor digitado pelo usuário assim:

```
gets(cpf);
```

Logo em seguida, chamo uma função que percorre este array "cpf", caractere por caractere, fazendo cast para converter string para int, visando identificar a presença de um não int.

A chamada ficou assim:

```
        if ((valida_cnh_cpf(cpf)) = 1) {
            printf("Erro, informe somente números para CPF\n");
            system("pause");
            system("cls");
            menu();
        }
```

E a função foi declarada assim:

```
int valida_cnh_cpf(cpf_cnh) {
    fflush(stdin);
    int cpf_cnh_convertido[11];
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i <= strlen(cpf_cnh); i++) {
        cpf_cnh_convertido[i] = (int) cpf_cnh[i];
        if (isdigit(cpf_cnh_convertido[i])) {
            return 0;
        } else {
            i = strlen(cpf_cnh) + 1;
            return 1;
        }
    }
}
```

O problema está logo na compilação. Recebo o seguinte erro apontando para a linha do for:

> [Warning] passing argument 1 of 'strlen' makes pointer from integer
>   without a cast

Pelo que entendi, falta fazer cast em algum lugar. Poderiam me ajudar a identificar?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tem diversos pontos que precisam de atenção:

## Atribuição vs Comparação

O primeiro foi identificado pelo compilador. Você pôs apenas um `=` dentro do `if`, portanto você está fazendo uma atribuição, não uma comparação. Correção: use `==`

## Verificar se são todos dígitos

O outro o compilador não apontou: só retorne 0 no final da função. Se você retornar logo no começo, ele vai dar um falso positivo para `123oliveira4`. Também vale lembrar que você deve tipar o parâmetro. É que você não precisa ir até `strlen`, basta parar antes. Tem como fazer esse laço de modo melhor, mas não vou entrar nos detalhes agora.

Ah, e não precisa interagir com a `stdin` se você não for ler dela nessa função. Sem `fflush` desnecessário.

Também não precisa dessa "conversão forçada" par inteiro. Perguntar por `isdigit` é o suficiente.

Solução:

```
int valida_cnh_cpf(char *cpf_cnh) {
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < strlen(cpf_cnh); i++) {
        if (!isdigit(cpf_cnh[i])) {
            return 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

## Não leia com `gets`

Use `fgets(cpf, 11, stdin)`

Comment: Jefferson, muito obrigado.

Comment: @Ângelo, precisando, só continuar fazendo perguntas boas que respostas boas brotarão do chão como se fosses ervas daninhas =)